# Is "shopt -s lastpipe" efficient?

Tags: bash

There are recommendations all over the place to avoid unnecessary subshells. It makes me wonder whether it is efficient to generally have the `lastpipe` option enabled so that the last command in a pipeline is not executed in a subshell?

Comment: ksh behaves that way out-of-the-box, and folks generally don't complain. That said, bash's implementation is picky about when it works and when it doesn't; I can see wanting to keep it off-by-default for better consistency with interactive shells (with job control enabled, which puts them in the "when it doesn't" category).

Comment: ...that said, there's a lot of fuzziness / room for opinion here; I'm not sure it's a question that lends itself to a concrete answer.

Comment: I didn't think this might be opinion based since there might be evidence it really is more efficient :) Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Oh, it really *is* more efficient, but whether that efficiency is worth pursuing is a judgment on whether one considers that difference enough to justify the compatibility delta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*More efficient*? Sure.

*Best-practice*? That depends on what you prioritize.

If you care about consistent behavior between interactive and noninteractive shells, `shopt -s lastpipe` on bash has substantial tradeoffs, because it has no effect when job control is enabled. Thus, scripts which depend (either intentionally or implicitly) on the last piece of a pipeline running in the same process can silently fail if that code is transported to a context where the lastpipe flag is either unset or ineffective on account of implementation constraints.